# How to grep from background process?

Tags: bash, shell, grep, sh

I have a script, that runs an app.
The app produces some output
I need to grep from the output in order to verify it
How can I accomplish this?

For instance;

script1.sh

```
    #!/bin/sh

    app1 &
    app2

    ******
    Output:
    app1 -> "App1"
    app2 -> "APp2"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use nohup to catch the script output and grep in nohup file. Below is how you'll execute the command in nohup:

```
nohup ./script.sh &
```

It will create a `nohup.out` file in current directory which can be used for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a named pipe over a file produced by `nohup`. The reason is subtle, but important. Let's say that your background application takes 10 seconds to execute and produces a decent amount of data. For `nohup` to work, you will need to wait for the background application to finish before you can process the data from that file. You will miss out on the befit of using a background process in the first place which is parallelism. This is true not just from `nohup` output, but for any regular file.

Here is an example of not waiting for the background file to finish executing:

```
$ { for i in {0..100}; do echo $i; sleep 0.1; done } > outfile &
[1] 2069
$ grep 1 outfile
1
```

As you can see, the grep process immediately processes the file and exits before the background application is finished writing data.

When using a named pipe, the foreground process, `grep` in this case, will know that it needs to wait for the pipe to close. Notice the difference:

```
$ mkfifo outpipe
$ { for i in {0..100}; do echo $i; sleep 0.1; done } > outpipe &
[1] 2173
$ grep 1 outpipe
1
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
21
31
41
51
61
71
81
91
100
```

With a named pipe, we can use the output of the background process just as if it were coming from a pipe.